# Test In app purchase with out submitting app in iTunes and not verified Products

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, paypal-sandbox, itunes

How to test in app purchase in sandbox mode without submitting app to itunes and also unverified product ? Is it possible to do ? Please let me know, thanks in advance.

Comment: @Kalpesh It really doesn't inspire confidence that your edit claims to fix "speeling", or that you attempted to do so and still left quite a few errors in (or introduced them? I'm genuinely not sure)

Comment: @KalpeshPanchasara there is no space before interpunction marks; iTunes has a capital T, never leave a *thanks*  in the question, and, as QPays said, properly do your grammar, not a sentence which doesn't flow. Please stop editing questions like this, solely to get the badge. If you edit, make it a substantial improvement of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can test your in-app Purchasing for Sandbox without submitting it to the app store and without getting your product validated by Apple.

You can follow these steps:

1) Create the app using a developer account and enter in the app purchase.

2) Create the app in iTunes, and enter which products you want to check in the in-app purchase in the feature tab.

3) Create a Sandbox tester email in iTunes.

4) Provide all data, otherwise you will get Metadata Missing error.

5) Uncheck Sales in Products.

6) Implement in-app Purchase in your app.

7) Make sure to clearly sign out your iTunes account from your device.

8) Now you are able to use in-app purchase in your app.

9) Make sure you use your Sandbox tester email only.

Comment: For a proper spelling and grammatical edit, I refer to mine on this answer. Please take care of that next time you make an edit.